# How to display widget using conditional for product single page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up widget display on the product page with conditional `is_product_tag( 'hans' )`, but the widget does not appear.

I'm using WordPress 5.2.2, WooCommerce 3.6.5 & Widget Logic (*plugin*) 5.10.4

**Edit 1**: I tried the below conditional on the single product page, but it didn't work:

```
has_term( 'hans' )
is_product && is_product_tag ( 'hans')
is_product_tag ('hans')
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting  . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong condition here. The conditional tag only works if the product tag archive for `hans` is being displayed. As mentioned in the question - you are on the product single page. So, your condition will always return false.

You can use:

```
has_term('hans', 'product_tag');
```

If this does not work in the widget logic plugin, you can use the same condition in PHP before displaying the widget.